# Is FCM token refreshed on OS update?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

We are integrating firebase in one of our mobile app. This is our doubt 'Is FCM token refreshed on OS update?', we know about these scenarios:

The registration token may change when:

1. The app is restored on a new device
2. The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
3. The user clears app data.

Answer (score 1):

you're right The registration token may change when:

1. The app is restored on a new device
2. The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
3. The user clears app data.

but as far as I know  **it doesn't change on OS update**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it doesn't change on OS update.
Since Firebase documentation only tells us this:

> The registration token may change when:
> -The app deletes Instance ID
> -The app is restored on a new device
> -The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> -The user clears app data.

By a OS update, you are neither changing device or reinstalling apps. So, no token change should happen.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not change on your mobile device OS update.

But it should not bother you because if you have handled the scenario mentioned on FCM doc where token may change and one should always

- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

Then if in case if it did happen in the latest OS then also you will be taken care of.

I did update many of our testing devices OS and token remain the same.
So only thing is just to make sure that we are always retrieving our token from the device to have the latest rather than saving once on the server and thinking it will never change.